# How to use mongoose full-text search for numeric values?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, full-text-search

We are using `mongoose` full-text search and it is somehow working fine for textual values. How can we use it for numeric values? For example, we have a `mongoose` Schema for **product** as

```
const productSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    type: String,
    description: String,
    price: Number,
    rating: Number,
},{
    collection: 'products',
    timestamps: true
});

productSchema.index({'$**' : 'text'});
```

And searching as

```
product.find({
        $text: { $search: req.query.query, $caseSensitive: false }
    }).exec((e, products) => {
        res.status(200).send({
            message: 'Products',
            products
        });
    })
```

It is giving correct results for queries `Fresh fruits`, `brown eggs`, `Dairy items`, etc 
 **BUT** it is not giving correct results for queries `Fruits having ratings more than 4`, `Dairy items under 300 in price`, etc.

I'm wondering if this is possible using `mongooes`?

For query `Dairy items under 300 in price`, I'm expecting all the dairy products price **less then or equal to 300**